# How to do continuous asymetric encryption for data storage on embedded system

Tags: security, encryption, embedded

This is more a "concept" question than a real programing one. However, having to constraint to work on embedded systems have to be kept in mind.

Here is a little bit of context : I am working on a project that uses an stm32 prototyping board (STM32G431KB to be precise, bare-metal (so C / C++) ) and my goal is to safely store sensitive data in files so that only an authenticated person would be able to read them. I would like to avoid symmetric encryption as it is not as safe as asymmetric.

Files are stored on an SDCard. And the particularity is that I need to encrypt them "on the fly". I plan to acquire data approximately every second and add them to a file. Re-encrypting the whole file at each data save is not a solution as these ones may be large.

So, my question is : how could I achieve this?

I am completely new to this kind of concerns and would like to know if someone more experienced could share a few tips or things I could search. I assume that hybrid encryption could be the most suitable regarding my constraints, however, I am not sure this would be a correct way to use it :

- Generate a pair of private/public key and store the private on the device
- Using the public key to encrypt a symmetric key generated on a trusted host
- Get this key on device startup and use it to encrypt the file using CBC encryption

What would be the flaws of such a setup?

**PS** : just to clarify, the device is not connected to internet. The only interactions possible with a host would be over serial communication or just reading/writing data to the sdcard

Comment: Just to add some details: are you using a filesystem? Which libraries are you using to write to the SD?

Comment: I believe this webinar would be a great starting point for you https://www.hcc-embedded.com/news-and-events/webinars/encryption-for-embedded-file-systems

Comment: I was planning on using a fs, probably fat32 as it is the most common and easy to setup. Ext4 otherwise... But this is *not fixed* at the moment and I am just willing to take whatever is the most adapted for this usage.

Thanks @Fra93 ! This seems like a very nice introduction!